# Run sql-server query on 2 servers, one local and one on air

Tags: sql-server

I need to run query that will run on two servers.

One is local (Server1), and one on 192.144.22.22 (Server2)

I try this:

```
SELECT  *
FROM    [Db1].[dbo].table1 A
INNER JOIN [Server2].[Db1].[dbo].table2 B 
ON A.Id = B.Id
```

but this work fine because the two database is on the local machine.

How to do it ?

Comment: how is this question related to jquery?

Answer (score 1):

You can use Linked server to do that

from [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-IN/library/ms188279.aspx)

> Linked servers are configured to enable the Database Engine to execute
>   a Transact-SQL statement that includes tables in another instance of
>   SQL Server, or another database product such as Oracle.

[MSDN page for how to create a Linked server.](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-IN/library/ff772782.aspx)

> You can configure a linked server by using SQL Server Management
>   Studio or by using the sp_addlinkedserver (Transact-SQL) statement.
>   OLE DB providers vary greatly in the type and number of parameters
>   required. For example some providers require you to provide a security
>   context for the connection using sp_addlinkedsrvlogin (Transact-SQL).
>   Some OLE DB providers allow SQL Server to update data on the OLE DB
>   source. Others provide only read-only data access. For information
>   about each OLE DB provider, consult documentation for that OLE DB
>   provider.